# How do I calculate the number of lines in a mesh?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have *n* number of points, and I put them all in a 2-dimensional grid in a circle pattern. I make lines between all of them, e.g. every point now has a line that connects it to every other point.

How do I calculate how many lines there are?

Comment: Have you tried doing the problem for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ to search for a pattern?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Well, I can't believe I didn't think about doing that... that would have been better than ask here, especially since it's this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your $n$ points, you have $n-1$ lines to the remaining points. But each line is connected to two points, and I don't want to double count, so the answer is

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Each of $n$ points has a line connecting it with each of remainig $n-1$ points, thus we can say there are $n(n-1)$ junctions. However, a line joining point $A$ with point $Q$ is the same one which joins $Q$ with $A$ – each line was counted twice, so the answer is a half of that: $$\frac{n(n-1)}2$$

Putting it another way, there are $\binom n 2$ pairs in $n$–element set, so there are $$\binom n 2 = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} = \frac{n(n-1)}2$$
lines joining those pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different combinational formula for it. Which is given by ${n \choose 2}=\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}$ NOTE :[only a better way to represent it]. And a bit too long for a comment.